# how to get exact answer without losing information

Tags: java

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int big = 1234567890;
        float approx = big;
        System.out.println(big - (int)approx);
    }
}
```

I got the above code from the Java language specification. My doubt is there any possible way to get the right answer. I used strictfp but I got the same result (see the below code):

```
strictfp class Test6 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int big = 1234567890;
        float approx = big;
        System.out.println(big - (int)approx);
    }
}
```

This outputs `-46`.

Comment: `strictfp` will take you in the other direction, if anything.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels It basically limits all floating point calculations to ensure constant behavior on all platforms. It's very rarely used, though.

Comment: @arshajii: I've not heard of it before. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `BigInteger` and `BigDecimal`

Additionally depending on your needs, you can just assign it to a `double` instead of `float`, it has higher precision

Comment: @rajeev That's really your job.

Comment: "can you modify my code" ... not the most inspiring follow-up you could have given.

Comment: -1 to your question @rajeev for asking others to do your coding. Please try to use ideas here to make modifications yourself. Show your attempts if it doesn't work.

Comment: @rajeev [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) and [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html)